# Event doesn't trigger until the current event is finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, asterisk

I am developing an application using Asterisk.NET Library, and I am subscribed to an event "NewStateEvent" to get the incoming calls from the server.. 
Now, I noticed that The NewState Event doesnt occur again until the last NewStateEvent is finished. I assume that its working on a single thread; that will start another thread only when the last one is finished... (I had to Invoke form to use form controls in the event)...
Is there any idea to allow mumltiple instances of a thread within my NewState Event ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're doing something that takes a bit of time in the event handler? In that case, unless you have access to modify the library itself, I'd suggest immediately kicking off a thread of your own in the event handler and do your long-running task on that. That would avoid locking it all up and you'd be able to receive other events.

There are a bunch of ways to do that. `BackgroundWorker`, using the `ThreadPool`, using async methods or simply kicking off a new thread manually.

Comment: Can I use a Queue for this,, ?? Enqueueing the parameters, and subscribe to queue events for event methods ???

Comment: Sure you could queue up all events you receive, and process them on another thread. Note that if you just process them on one thread, you'll pretty much be back where you started with only one event begin processed at a time.